# air pressure to assist lift on a Race boat

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, drag, aerodynamics, fluid-statics

We have a 25 ft race hull with Jet drive pump (we race 30+ mile legs), we are hitting sppeds @150mph. lowering the hydronic drag is a challenge, i am thinking about installing a air injection system into the bottom of the boat. If i install 40 holes (20 ) on each side facing down and flush with the water at 1 1/6 or 1/8 in size @50 psi how much lift will this give us? will the injection of air lower the drag?

Comment: saz, just out of curiosity, how many HP does your engine develop in full race mode? I'm asking because at 150 MPH, aerodynamic drag will be important, and I suspect your hull is already "flying" above the water (in ground effect), and when it intermittently touches down it's probably already sliding on a mixture of air bubbles and water.

Comment: we @ 1700hp, yes the hulls are for sure out of the water - i beleive you are correct we are to the point where aerodynamic drag needs to addressed. I am on a learning curve trying to understand that drag

Comment: ever consider a hull that is actually a wing that would "fly" the hull a foot or so off the water, with almost nothing in the water except for the jet intake? flying in ground effect like this furnishes the lowest drag possible... I ask the question because I have watched enough speedboat crashes where the boat turns briefly into an uncontrollable airplane to know that at those speeds, you MUST design the hull to fly on purpose and not crash when its bow pitches up and it grabs air. I have some ideas we could discuss...

Comment: looking forward to chatting - i sent you a note on your website

Answer (score 0):

Penguins use something like an air injection system for emergencies. They stay warm while in water by trapping air under their feathers. When seals chase them they can get an extra burst of speed by squeezing the air out.

This idea has been used to lubricate the hulls of container ships.

See this [National Geographic article](http://ngm.nationalgeographic.com/2012/11/emperor-penguins/hodges-text).

Answer (score 0):

At that speed, you're definitely operating an [*aircraft in ground effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_effect_vehicle), so issues like balance and decalage must be considered. What that means is, for stability, there is a center of gravity CG, which is somewhat forward of the center of aerodynamic lift, while there is another surface that gives a pitch-up moment with speed. This can be either a tail surface lifting downward, or a forward canard lifting upward. That surface is *trimmed* for different speeds. There also needs to be a tail fin for yaw-wise stability.

Then you need to account for crosswinds. In aircraft, when they are above the ground, they simply crab. When they are on the ground, they use the wheels' sideways resistance, and then use the tailfin rudder to keep them from turning into the wind. It is worked with pedals.

Also they can roll a bit to the left or right, so as to tilt the lift vector into the wind. So if the wind is from the right, they can use right bank and left rudder, called "cross controlled".

I suspect the boat when in contact with the water has enough keel resistance (which also should be aft of the CG) to counteract side-slip, but you will need the rudder, either water or air or both, to prevent turning into the wind.

But whenever the boat is out of the water, it's an airplane. And even when it's in the water, it's an airplane on a runway. Every pilot has learned the dictum "fly it till you tie it". I suspect your boat driver should take flying lessons.

Comment: We are using front adjustible canards  for bow lifting upward.  But looking for some new ideas

Comment: @saz: Good. I would expect the canards to have trim to match airspeed, as in canard aircraft like the [*Long-EZ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutan_Long-EZ). Usually as a pilot gets up to higher speed there is more nose-up tendency due to the decalage, so he has to give forward stick pressure. He can relax that by applying nose-down trim which basically pushes on the stick for him. Then when he slows down he does the opposite. I wonder if your boat pilot needs to do that when he's running.

Comment: the driver is moving the canards steady, as you turn, wind conditions, smooth water, rough water - you are on the wings lots. to the point it needs a system of control . the drive has a tough time keeping up

Comment: @saz: Interesting. Is the boat designed for aerodynamic stability? I'm a sometime pilot, and [*here's my favorite e-book on the subject.*](https://www.av8n.com/how/htm/aoastab.html#sec-basic-stability) The basic idea is, when your boat is airborne, it has a center of lift, and the CG of the boat should be *a bit forward* of the center of lift. Furthermore, the canards should take up that forward weight (or if you have a tail, it should lift down). Then the craft has a happy airspeed (controlled by trim). If it's loaded too far aft, you get pitch instability - bucking bronco.

Comment: You can see that in Wright Flyer videos, [*like this one*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jk4ShDw_TAs), where the pilot is fighting the pitch instability, probably because the CG is too far aft.

Comment: we are for sure fight to stay stable , the boat is not designed for aeerodynamics - i would like to modify it so it is but only designed for what the builders best trial and error style is.

Comment: @saz: Interesting. I would think if the builders got some input from an aerodynamicist it would give a competitive advantage. I hope you're able to do that.

Comment: that is what or who i am looking for but I/we have not found that person so far - we are looking -do you know anyone with this knowledge and willing

Comment: @saz: If I were you, I would ask [*John S. Denker*](https://www.av8n.com/how/). The worst he could do is say "get lost" :) Or maybe Rutan's operation [*Scaled Composites*](http://www.scaled.com/).